# Ponto em atributo de Classe de Modelo é possível?

Tags: c#, xml, web-service, classes, soap

Esse é um esquema xml de requisião de um WebMethod:

```
  <RetrieveClienteRequest>
     <model query="">
        <keys query="" >
           <cliente.cnpj type="String"></cliente.cnpj>
        </keys>
        <instance>
           <cliente.cnpj type="String"></cliente.cnpj>
        </instance>
     </model>
  </RetrieveClienteRequest>
```

O WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument RetrieveClienteRequest(model model)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    ClienteBusiness objClienteBusiness = new ClienteBusiness();
    xmlDoc = objClienteBusiness.getCustomer(model);
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

O problema é que o atributo *cliente.cnpj tem ponto(.)* e na Classe de Modelo NÃO pode haver **ponto**, como contornar isso ?

Tentei assim:

```
public class keys
    {
        [Column("cliente.cnpj"), Display(Name = "cliente.cnpj")]
        public string cliente_cnpj { get; set; }
    }
```

Estou utilizando o SoapUI para fazer teste e o atributo cliente_cnpj vem com o "_" e não pode, tem que retornar com "." (ponto).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:RetrieveClienteRequest>
         <tem:model>
            <tem:Keys>
               <tem:cliente_cnpj>?</tem:cliente_cnpj>
            </tem:Keys>
            <tem:instance>
               <tem:cliente_cnpj>?</tem:cliente_cnpj>
            </tem:instance>
         </tem:model>
      </tem:RetrieveClienteRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: o "." é um caracter inválido para isso, ele vai ser substituido por "_", de onde vem essa estrutura de `<cliente.cnpj>`?

Comment: Essa classe eu que estou fazendo para atender uma aplicação Phyton que irá consumir esse serviço.

Comment: @Leandro Angelo será que se eu substituir minhas `Classes de Modelo .cs` por [Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)  resolve ?